# How to get GameElements (RigidBody) size in Unity?

Tags: unity

I've made a prefab consisting of a Cube which I've first scaled to more resemble a brick. There's also a Rigidbody added to the cube (in the prefab). Now I want to use that prefab in a c# script to make a wall out of multiple bricks.

My question is, how can I access the dimensions of my brick (width, height, the z dimension size) so that in my script I can make bricks which are placed one next to the other (and then one on top of the other)?

I've looked at the documentation for [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) and [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) but I can't find anything helpful.

Just for refference, my script so far is:

```
public GameObject brick;

void Start () {
        Instantiate(this.brick, new Vector3(0.01326297f, -30.07855f, 100f), Quaternion.identity);
        // int brickWidth = this.brick.????;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) ?

I guess you can achieve what you're looking for using :

```
float brickWidth = brick.renderer.bounds.size.x;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just must make the brickWidth variable into a float.